# Problem: MariaDb server requires quoted identifiers (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: mariadb

On Ubuntu 22.04, in mysql shell, quoting all identifiers works, e.g.:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'actryx_knowhow_bookstack' and table_name = 'migrations' and table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
+---------------+--------------------------+------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------------+------------------+-----------+
| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA             | TABLE_NAME | TABLE_TYPE | ENGINE | VERSION | ROW_FORMAT | TABLE_ROWS | AVG_ROW_LENGTH | DATA_LENGTH | MAX_DATA_LENGTH | INDEX_LENGTH | DATA_FREE | AUTO_INCREMENT | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME         | CHECK_TIME | TABLE_COLLATION    | CHECKSUM | CREATE_OPTIONS | TABLE_COMMENT | MAX_INDEX_LENGTH | TEMPORARY |
+---------------+--------------------------+------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------------+------------------+-----------+
| def           | actryx_knowhow_bookstack | migrations | BASE TABLE | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    |         74 |            221 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |             75 | 2023-03-11 10:32:31 | 2023-03-11 10:32:33 | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |     NULL |                |               |                0 | N         |
+---------------+--------------------------+------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------------+------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

However, with unquoted identifiers (... all regular syntax though ...)  it doesn't:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = actryx_knowhow_bookstack and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'actryx_knowhow_bookstack' in 'where clause'
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is litteraly **nothing** wrong.

You are querying the information_schema.tables table. This is the identifier from your query. table_name, table_schema and table_type are all VARCHAR (string) columns from the table being queried, thus all values must be passed as strings.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Then the problem is the software generating the `select` statement, and not in the db. Helpful!